# How do I fix the problem behind "THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_ERROR" when using Google's API Explorer to send a Firebase Cloud Messaging message?

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to create a very simple Web app that can send and receive messages (including Push notifications) via Firebase Cloud Messaging. I want to try testing the ability to receive test messages sent from the Google API Explorer. However, I am running into a curious error as just about any API call from [the relevant API URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages/send) will return the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
        "errorCode": "THIRD_PARTY_AUTH_ERROR"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For reference, here is the message that I am trying to send:

```
{
  "message": {
    "token": "[FCM_TOKEN]",
    "notification": {
      "title": "New Notification",
      "body": "Sample Text"
    }
  }
}
```

I also note that when I add `"validate_only": true` to the message, that the error goes away and the send request succeeds (though this is of no help, as that disables actually sending the message).

I am stumped, becuse the hint that pops up suggests that my OAuth2 credentials are invalid, though I leave the OAuth2 credential option checked and go through the authorization popup to provide my credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the web app on Firefox, perhaps?
I have been running around my tail with this same issue for days now, and today I've found that there is an issue on Firefox, while this does work on Chrome:
[Similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218243/fcm-messages-not-being-sent-to-firefox)
[The issue on the Firebase repository on Github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6523)

Although not a proper answer, I hope this helps.