# FCM messages not being sent to firefox

Tags: python, firebase, firefox, firebase-cloud-messaging

So we were testing FCM messages but when I try to send messages to a token generated through firefox it gives me an error stating **firebase_admin._messaging_utils.ThirdPartyAuthError: Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service**

Also, FCM message delivery is inconsistent on chrome

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fcm_noti/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/firebase_admin/messaging.py", line 348, in send
    resp = self._client.body(
  File "fcm_noti/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 131, in body
    resp = self.request(method, url, **kwargs)
  File "fcm_noti/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/firebase_admin/_http_client.py", line 119, in request
    resp.raise_for_status()
  File "fcm_noti/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/graphy-repo/messages:send

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fcm_noti/tester_org.py", line 15, in <module>
    print(messaging.send(message))
  File "fcm_noti/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/firebase_admin/messaging.py", line 116, in send
    return _get_messaging_service(app).send(message, dry_run)
  File "fcm_noti/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/firebase_admin/messaging.py", line 355, in send
    raise self._handle_fcm_error(error)
firebase_admin._messaging_utils.ThirdPartyAuthError: Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. FCM notifications have stopped working completely on Firefox. I contacted Firebase Support but they are reporting that there is no known outage going on right now and asked me to provide reproducible code. Conversation is still ongoing.

Comment: Facing the same issue. FCM returns "Auth error from APNS or Web Push Service" when trying to send to a Firefox token.

Comment: Firebase Support has reproduced this issue and they are now working on it.

Comment: Is there any link to some official issue in Firebase I can use to follow the progress on this?